# Не удается получить доступ к сайту Не удалось найти IP-адрес сервера php.loc

Tags: php, openserver

При попытке открыть файл через openserver 5.2.2 выдается ошибка (скриншот 6). Как решить? Облазил весь интернет, но так и не нашел решения. Расположение всего, чего только можно прикрепил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно какое-то правило идет на ключевое слово php или loc. Порекомендую и то  и то переименовать и попробовать. Например php-test.local

Comment: @СергейМишин нет, все аналогично даже при переименовании

Comment: А попробуйте в другом браузере. В хроме например. И написать сразу через http://  Может опера так глючит

Comment: @СергейМишин Не удается получить доступ к сайтуНе удалось найти IP-адрес сервера php-test.local.
Выполните поиск по запросу php test local в Google
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. Все аналогично и в хроме

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Удалите настройки домена. Эти настройки используются если у Вашего
  сайта точка входа в другой папке (например public).
- Используйте в браузере http://php.loc и попробуйте другой
  браузер(Сергей Мишин прав).
- Запустите OpenServer от администратора

Comment: Я тебя обожаю <3